# How to use Unity Scripting with Vuforia

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces, vuforia, hololens

This maybe a stupid question but this keeps moving in my mind.
here's the situation.

I have a small application deployed in Hololens and using vuforia extensions, I'm able to track and recognize a real 3d object. I'm able to make holograms appear too, as long as holograms are children of the target object.
What I want to do is to activate or deactivate holograms that is not a child of the target object. I can't do it through code since the script i'm manipulating is a name space.
I tried putting methods inside the namespace itself but i keep having exceptions and nothing works.
I hope you can help me with this one.
Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Instantiate https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html
to create an object as soon as Vuforia has recognizes a specific target (Wich you can check by using one of the targetablemanagers.)